# Entity Framework Unwanted Foreign Keys

Tags: c#, wpf, entity-framework, ef-code-first, foreign-keys

I have the following two entities in a `C#`, `WPF`, `EF6` application:

```
public class SaleDepartment
{
    public int SaleDepartmentId { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public int? TaxId { get; set; }
}

public class Tax
{
    public int TaxId { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public decimal Rate { get; set; }
}
```

The issue I have is that I only want the SaleDepartment entity to point to Tax, I'm not interested in Tax pointing back to SaleDepartment and therefore creating unnecessary keys in SaleDepartment. So adding:

```
public virtual Tax Tax { get; set; }
```

to my SaleDepartment entity together with:

```
HasOptional(p => p.Tax).WithMany().HasForeignKey(p => p.TaxId);
```

to my entity configuration creates an unnecessary key of

```
FK_SaleDepartment_Tax_TaxId
```

Any ideas on me still being able to have my `public virtual Tax Tax` but without it creating this `FK_SaleDepartment_Tax_TaxId` key?

Comment: Are you saying it's creating two foreign keys. One in the SaleDepartment table and one in the Tax table? From the look of that key it only looks like it's creating the key between SaleDepartment and tax which I would expect since you are defining the relationship as a one to many.

Comment: @Dismissile, it's creating the 'FK_SalesDepartment_Tax_TaxId' in the SalesDepartment table, which I don't want as I'm not interested in Tax being the parent of SalesDepartment and therefore looking after it's child records, but I am wanting SalesDepartment to know which Tax it's related to. TaxId will never change, and neither will it be deletable (soft deletes will be in place).

Comment: You can't have a relationship like this without having a foreign key. You are telling Entity Framework that there is a relationship between the two entities and that Tax is the parent. The only way to get rid of that foreign key is to remove the relationship or delete the FK manually in the database, but then you could run into data integrity problems.

Comment: @Dismissile Thanks, I was hoping for a work around, but I need SalesDescription to point to Tax but I don't want copious amounts of foreign keys (and I'm talking more about my other entities than the two mentioned here) where I won't be allowing a delete or changing of the parent's ID. Oh well, I guess I'll be keeping my stack of foreign keys then, but worth asking non the less. Thanks.